# How I can change gridview checkbox value in form load?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to change grid checkbox value in form load,the problem is when I run and tracing the code it's work fine but nothing changes on the grid.

Code block:

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView3.Rows
    Dim c As Integer
    c = row.Cells(4).Value
    If c = 2 Then
        row.Cells(selctWin.Name).Value = True
    Else
       row.Cells(selctWin.Name).Value = False
    End If
Next
```

Comment: You could try add this `DataGridView3.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)` after for loop and check.

Comment: Instead of assigning the values in checkbox column values in front-end, include additional `bit` column in your sql query and assign the value either `true` or `false` based on the column `c`. It will reduces the extra for loop in your front-end.

Comment: add my code to `DataGridView3_CellContentClick` event and try

Comment: i used your idea, its work fine thank you very much for your support.

Comment: Glad it helped.. Please mark my answer as accepted (tick aside to the answer) and you may up vote also. Thanks! Happy coding!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below code:

```
Private Sub DataGridView3_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs)
    DataGridView3.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
End Sub
```

It will allow the changes to commit when cell content clicked (`checkboxCell` here) without ending edit mode. Refer this [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.commitedit(v=vs.110).aspx) more about `CommitEdit` method.